# ¿Cómo deserializar array JSon?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo este array json que estoy tratando de deserializar, pero me da error de: `Indice fuera de los límites la matriz`:
¿cómo obtengo los valores del array movies, los 2 elementos movies?
Estoy usando `Newtonsoft.Json`

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{\"Code\":\"AF0544\",\"shop\":\"Dallas E.U.\",\"movie\" : [{\"Id\":\"1024\", \"Title\":\"Pandora\"}, {\"Id\":\"1037\", \"Title\":\"The Fox and the girl\"}]}";
            RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            ro.movies = new Movies[0];
            string code = "";
            string shop = "";
            string movid = "";
            string movtitle = "";
            code = ro.Code;
            shop = ro.Shop;
            movid = ro.movies[0].Id;
            movtitle = ro.movies[0].Title;

            Console.WriteLine(code);
            Console.WriteLine(shop);         
            Console.WriteLine(movid);         
            Console.WriteLine(movtitle);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

public class RootObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public Movies[] movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movies
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: en tu json el array se llama 'movie' y al dess estas buscando por 'movies'

Comment: @LucianoMontañez, ya comprendo, pero aun así no sabría como llegar hasta ese punto, yo lo hice así por lo que 'movies' es el nombre de la clase, no?

Comment: Cuando haces `ro.movies = new Movies[0];` estas sobreescribiendo los valores que se _supone_ que deserializaste (digo se supone, ya que la propiedad se diferencia por una **`s`**). Elimina esa linea de codigo. Adicional en tu json la propiedad se llama `movie` y en el objeto `RootObject` la llamas `movies`. Practicamente tu problema es tipografico.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Vale, ahora veo porque no funcionaba, pero no me queda claro porque esta vez no tuve que inicializar la clase `Movies` como en otros casos.

Comment: `Newtonsoft.Json` ya inicializa el array y cada uno de los item del array. Si en tal caso en el json no viene una propiedad que si tiene el objeto base, entonces si tendras que inicializar siempre que sea el caso (si utilizaras la propiedad o no), de lo contrario esa propiedad quedara nula o con un valor por defecto en el caso de int, bool ... ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, el código quedó así:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = "{" +
                "\"Code\":\"AF0544\"," +
                "\"shop\":\"Dallas E.U.\"," +
                "\"movie\" : " +
                    "[" +
                        "{\"Id\":\"1024\", " +
                        "\"Title\":\"Pandora\"" +
                        "}, " +
                        "{\"Id\":\"1037\", " +
                        "\"Title\":\"The Fox and the girl\"" +
                        "}" +
                    "]" +
                "}";
            RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
            //ro.movies = new Movies[0];
            string code = "";
            string shop = "";
            string movid = "";
            string movtitle = "";
            string movid2 = "";
            string movtitle2 = "";

            code = ro.Code;
            shop = ro.Shop;
            movid = ro.movie[0].Id.ToString();
            movtitle = ro.movie[0].Title.ToString();
            movid2 = ro.movie[1].Id.ToString();
            movtitle2 = ro.movie[1].Title.ToString();

            Console.WriteLine(code);
            Console.WriteLine(shop);         
            Console.WriteLine(movid);         
            Console.WriteLine(movtitle);
            Console.WriteLine(movid2);
            Console.WriteLine(movtitle2);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
public class RootObject
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public Movies[] movie { get; set; }
}

public class Movies
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Un consejo para generar el string multi-line usa el `@` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100260/multiline-string-literal-in-c-sharp/25177497

Comment: @LeandroTuttini, Muchas gracias, aprendí algo nuevo y útil.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de: Indice fuera de los límites la matriz: era que casteaba mal el json y querias leer un indice del array que no existia. Querias leer el indice 2 y solo tenias 1 por ejemplo.
Te ordene mejor el codigo

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{" +
            "\"Code\":\"AF0544\"," +
            "\"shop\":\"Dallas E.U.\"," +
            "\"movie\" : " +
                "[" +
                    "{\"Id\":\"1024\", " +
                    "\"Title\":\"Pandora\"" +
                    "}, " +
                    "{\"Id\":\"1037\", " +
                    "\"Title\":\"The Fox and the girl\"" +
                    "}" +
                "]" +
            "}";
        RootObject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

        if (ro.movie.Length > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Code: " + ro.Code);
            Console.WriteLine("Shop:" + ro.Shop);
            for (int i = 0; i < ro.movie.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Id:" + ro.movie[i].Id.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("Title: " + ro.movie[i].Title.ToString());
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

        public class RootObject
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }
            public string Shop { get; set; }
            public Movies[] movie { get; set; }
        }

        public class Movies
        {
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
        }
```